# How do I calculate the amount of Time overlap between 2 Intervals in a table

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I want to calculate the amount of time that lies in between time intervals of differenz rows in a table.
Here is an example of what the data.frame would look like:

```
x <-tibble(name = c("Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4"),
           group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
           start = c("2020-10-01-10:00", "2020-10-01-12:00", "2020-10-01-16:00", "2020-10-01-16:00"),
           end = c("2020-10-01-16:00", "2020-10-01-18:00", "2020-10-01-20:00", "2020-10-01-23:00")) %>%
  mutate(start = lubridate::ymd_hm(start),
         end = lubridate::ymd_hm(end)) %>%
  mutate(time_interval = interval(start = start, end = end))
```

I would like to generate another column that displays the amount of hours that the time_intervals of the Persons in each group overlap.
I already looked for similar questions and functions but did not find any.
Is there a way in R to calculate the time overlap?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Isn´t the overlap across the intervals the difference between the latest start time and the earliest end time (if there is any overlap)? This could be calculated like this. If there is no overlap (= "negative" overlap) 0 is returned.

```
require(lubridate)
x %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(overlap = if_else(condition = max(start) < min(end), 
                           true = min(end) - max(start), 
                           false = 0))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   group [2]
  name    group start               end                 time_interval                                    overlap
  <chr>   <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>              <Interval>                                       <drtn> 
1 Person1 A     2020-10-01 10:00:00 2020-10-01 16:00:00 2020-10-01 10:00:00 UTC--2020-10-01 16:00:00 UTC 4 hours
2 Person2 A     2020-10-01 12:00:00 2020-10-01 18:00:00 2020-10-01 12:00:00 UTC--2020-10-01 18:00:00 UTC 4 hours
3 Person3 B     2020-10-01 16:00:00 2020-10-01 20:00:00 2020-10-01 16:00:00 UTC--2020-10-01 20:00:00 UTC 4 hours
4 Person4 B     2020-10-01 16:00:00 2020-10-01 23:00:00 2020-10-01 16:00:00 UTC--2020-10-01 23:00:00 UTC 4 hours
```